# Why is this Hilbert curve not drawing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics, fractals

```
import turtle as t
t.setup(500,500)
t.setworldcoordinates(0,0,500,500)
t.pu()
t.goto(0,0)
t.pd()
t.seth(0)
def N():
    t.pu()
    t.pd()
def B(c,d):
    t.right(90)
    c
    t.forward(5)
    t.left(90)
    d
    t.forward(5)
    d
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(5)
    c
    t.right(90)
def A(a,b):
    t.left(90)
    b
    t.forward(5)
    t.right(90)
    a
    t.forward(5)
    a
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(5)
    b
    t.left(90)      
t.seth(0)
A(A(None,None),B(None,None))
```

I'm trying to make a Hilbert curve but it is not working.
I am using the [L-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system)

Comment: Please share the error you are getting along with desired output - "why is this not working" is not enough

Comment: you provide `a,b,c,d` all as `None` to your function, Then you put them inside them as no-op ... why? You declare `def N()` but never use it - why?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is passing functions to other functions but isn't calling them correctly (you need parentheses and arguments.)  My best guess at patching this code is as follows:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def A(a, b, n):

    if n == 0:
        return

    turtle.left(90)
    b(a, b, n - 1)
    turtle.forward(5)
    turtle.right(90)
    a(a, b, n - 1)
    turtle.forward(5)
    a(a, b, n - 1)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(5)
    b(a, b, n - 1)
    turtle.left(90)

def B(c, d, n):

    if n == 0:
        return

    turtle.right(90)
    c(c, d, n - 1)
    turtle.forward(5)
    turtle.left(90)
    d(c, d, n - 1)
    turtle.forward(5)
    d(c, d, n - 1)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(5)
    c(c, d, n - 1)
    turtle.right(90)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, 500, 500)

turtle = Turtle()

A(A, B, 7)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]